# Why am I getting a "Cannot be resolved" error in java?

Tags: java

I am still pretty new to Java and I'm wondering why I'm getting "Website cannot be resolved" when I'm making a ReadableByteChannel:

```
Date now = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("D");
String day = simpledateformat.format(now);
System.out.println(day);
String ws = "http://wallpapercave.com/wp/hMwO9WT.jpg";

try {
    URL Website = new URL(ws);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(Website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("weed.jpg");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: because `Website` is defined for the scope of the `try` and wont "exist" anymore once you´re out of the `try` block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `Website` inside the scope of the try-catch block, hence it is not visible outside that block to the rest of your method.

One quick fix would be to just declare it before the `try` begins, e.g.

```
URL website = null;
try {
    website = new URL(ws);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("weed.jpg");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

You might want to also check that `website` be defined before using it, or you could even move the final three lines above into a try-catch block.  Note that I used `website` as the variable name, in line with Java coding conventions that variable names should begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: When I declare it before the try block, it throws: "Duplicate local variable Website"

Comment: @CrimsonK9 This is likely because you have `URL website` appearing inside the `try` block.  Don't _declare_ the website variable twice, this is what the error message is telling you.